# gpg: no valid OpenPGP error when I try to install yarn on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, openpgp

I am trying to install yarn on Ubuntu 18.04.

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable

I am trying to follow all steps from the link.

[image]

but I get no valid OpenPGP data found. error when I try to do something with

curl blah blah.. (link says I must need configure the repository)

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of text. Please edit your question and copy and paste the text from the terminal and format the pasted text using the **{ }** icon above the edit window.

Comment: Do this: `wget --quiet -O - /tmp/pubkey.gpg  https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -` and see if it works.  If it still fails then your SSL is probably fubar.

Comment: @ThomasWard thanks for comment. I think that worked. But could u help me with this problem too? when I try this command, curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -
root@LAPTOP-BKN76S4O:~# sudo apt-get install -y nodejs  ubuntu shows me  such error:  E: Type 'gpg' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list.          Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: That sounds like a different question.